# Missing Right Parenthesis Error in JPQL

Tags: oracle, jpa, playframework

I have the following Oracle SQL query I want to execute as a NativeQuery in JPA with the Play Framework, but for some reason, I always get an ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error.

```
    SELECT 
        a.EMPLOYEE_ID,
        a.FIRST_NAME,
        a.LAST_NAME,
        a.EMAIL,
        a.PHONE_NUMBER,
        TO_CHAR(a.HIRE_DATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD') HIRE_DATE,
        a.JOB_ID,
        a.SALARY,
        a.COMMISSION_PCT,
        a.MANAGER_ID,
        a.DEPARTMENT_ID,
        CONCAT(b.FIRST_NAME, CONCAT(' ', b.LAST_NAME)) MANAGER_NAME,
        JOBS.JOB_TITLE,
        DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME 
    FROM 
        EMPLOYEES a
    LEFT JOIN 
        JOBS
        ON
        a.JOB_ID = JOBS.JOB_ID
    LEFT JOIN 
        EMPLOYEES b
        ON
        a.MANAGER_ID = b.EMPLOYEE_ID
    LEFT JOIN 
        DEPARTMENTS
        ON
        a.DEPARTMENT_ID = DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID
    ORDER BY 
        a.EMPLOYEE_ID
        ASC
```

I tried testing this query in the Oracle SQL Developer and it works, so I don't know if JPA automatically inserts an open left parenthesis in the query. The Play console doesn't really help much since it doesn't point out exactly where the ORA-00907 error is trapped in.

Comment: The query itself is correct, so I doubt we'll be able to help with the code you posted. Whatever it is wrapped in must be what causes the problem.

Comment: I used a StringBuilder to make this query, but would just writing it as a single string variable make a difference?

Comment: No idea - I can only help with SQL. Let's wait for the app developers read your question and try to help. Good luck!

Comment: Show us your real code. The bug is most probably there. Also show the complete exception stack trace.

Comment: Any exception has a stack trace. Any JPA provider has a log that tells you what actual query was invoked. Don't see them here

Comment: Nevermind. Problem solved, turns out that some of the StringBuilder appends lacked a space, which caused the wild errors. Can someone close this question?